# Move Multiple FIles using CMD prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to move multiple files, but there are too many to do that manually.   Instead I am trying to use CMD prompt, but I have just started using it.

I can not use the copy cmd as I do not have enough space left on the hard disk.

I have to move a list of files from multiple folders.

---

Example. Source location files -

```
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\21 Jump Street (2012).avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\25th Hour (2002).avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\3 10 To Yuma\3.10 to Yuma.avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\500 Days Of Summer (2009).avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\A Dangerous Method (2011).avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\A Few Good Men (1992).avi"
"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\A very Harold & Kumar Christmas.avi"
```

I want to move these in the specific folders which i have already created multiple folders using the MD cmd in prompt.

---

Example. The final Destination folders that I have already created-

```
"E:\G\DM3\21 Jump Street (2012)"
"E:\G\DM3\25th Hour (2002)"
"E:\G\DM3\3 10 To Yuma (2007)"
"E:\G\DM3\500 Days Of Summer (2009)"
"E:\G\DM3\A Dangerous Method (2011)"
"E:\G\DM3\A Few Good Men (1992)"
"E:\G\DM3\A Very Harold And Kumar Christmas (2011)"
```

---

Example of the CMD I tried using -

```
move /y <"E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\Thor_(2011).mkv">    <"E:\G\DM3\Thor (2011)">
```

The cmd has failed and no files moves to the designated folders. What am I missing?

---

Answer (score 3):

Why did you add "<" and ">" in the `move` command?
Simply remove it and try again. 
`move /y "E:\G\Downloaded movies 2\Thor_(2011).mkv" "E:\G\DM3\Thor (2011)"`

Answer (score 0):

I want to move all my text files on the desktop in one file:

```
cd c:\users\user\desktop\text files
move c:\users\user\desktop*txt
msg %username% done
```

First, you change the dir to the destination file. Then, you move whatever files you want, and they will be in the destination file.